# How do I subtract two results from a SELECT statement within that statement?

Tags: mysql

This pulls back two int values of yesterday and today. I'd like to subtract the two results from within the statement in a third column called difference:

```
SELECT (
 SELECT COUNT(*)
 FROM collectors_users 
 WHERE DATE(dateadded) = CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY
) AS yesterday, COUNT(*) AS today 
FROM collectors_users 
WHERE DATE(dateadded) = CURDATE()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to repeat the expressions.  SQL (in general) does not allow you to re-use column aliases in the same `SELECT`.  You can simplify the logic to:

```
SELECT SUM(DATE(dateadded) = CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY) AS yesterday,
       SUM(DATE(dateadded) = CURDATE()) as today,
       (SUM(DATE(dateadded) = CURDATE()) - 
        SUM(DATE(dateadded) = CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY)
       ) as diff
FROM collectors_users
WHERE dateadded >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY AND
      dateadded < CURDATE() + INTERVAL 1 DAY;
```

Note that the logic for the `WHERE` clause covers two days.  Also, it does not use `DATE()`.  This would allow the query to use an index, if available.